# Simulate clicks in webrowser

Tags: c#, dom, web

how would I go about clicking a button ina  web page loaded in the webbrowser component? I want to click a button and display the resulting page in the webbrowser. I have googled and can not find the answer; can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If the element has an ID, you can use this;

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id").InvokeMember("click");
```

Although one direction I used recently is to find out the url that the button click takes you too, and navigate to that. This may not work for all sites..

Comment: Gah, the button does not have an ID. The link may work though; only textboxes will be an issue then.